# Plotly - second y axis colors

Tags: r, shiny, plotly, yaxis

I am plotting two values against one value (2x y-axis, one x-axis), but want to color them differently, each with a different set of hex colors. I've tried many settings, but the graph always shows only the first set of colors. Reproducible example:

```
mtcars %>% mutate(gear = as.factor(gear)) %>%
  plot_ly(x = ~ cyl, color = ~ gear) %>% 
    add_trace(y = ~ wt,
              type = "bar",
              colors = c("yellow", "red", "purple")) %>% 
    add_trace(y = ~ qsec,
              type = "scatter",
              mode = "lines + markers",
              yaxis = "y2",
              colors = c("blue", "green", "black")) %>% 
    layout(yaxis = list(side = "left"),
           yaxis2 = list(overlaying = "y", side = "right"))
```

Note that both traces are color-dependent on the same variable (gear), but I would like to use different colors ("warm" colors for WT variable, "cold" for QSEC variable). Now both traces are colored in "warm" colors.

Comment: You should provide a reproducible example.

Comment: code was changed to mtcars dataset, thanks

Comment: Hm, the bar graph looks totally different if you leave out the scatter plot. Not sure if the 3x3 bars are correct or the 3 single ones.